# Update rows if total column sum is less than X

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

I'm trying to figure out how to update rows in the table if their total size less than `x`.

Here is my setup:

```
create table test_limit (
       id int not null auto_increment primary key,
       folder varchar(255),
       status varchar(32) DEFAULT 'awaiting',
       size bigint unsigned default 0,
       request_id varchar(32)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into test_limit
  (folder, status, size)
values
  ('/tmp/AAA/bar', 'awaiting', 200 ),
  ('/tmp/AAA/bar', 'awaiting', 200 ),
  ('/tmp/AAA/bar', 'awaiting', 200 ),
  ('/tmp/BBB/bar', 'awaiting', 200 ),
  ('/tmp/BBB/bar', 'awaiting', 200 );
```

I have a table with 5 rows, each row has a size what I want to do is to update a group of rows that:

- has the same `folder` value
- status is not in `in_progress` or `created`
- has total limit of 400

I came up with the following update command:

```
SET @request_id='bbb';
UPDATE test_limit t1
  JOIN
     ( SELECT folder FROM test_limit WHERE status = 'awaiting' GROUP BY folder limit 1) t2
    ON t1.folder = t2.folder
  LEFT JOIN
     ( SELECT folder FROM test_limit WHERE status IN ('in_progress', 'created') GROUP BY folder limit 1) t3
    ON t1.folder = t3.folder
  JOIN
     ( SELECT id, @total := @total + size AS total  FROM (test_limit, (select @total := 0) t)  WHERE @total < 400 and status='awaiting') t4
    ON t1.id=t4.id
  SET t1.status = 'in_progress',
      t1.request_id = @request_id
  WHERE t1.status = 'awaiting' AND t3.folder is NULL;
```

But the problem is it is working first time, but doesn't work any other times:

```
mysql> select * from test_limit;
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------------+
| id | folder       | status      | size | request_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------------+
|  1 | /tmp/AAA/bar | in_progress |  200 | bbb        |
|  2 | /tmp/AAA/bar | in_progress |  200 | bbb        |
|  3 | /tmp/AAA/bar | awaiting    |  200 | NULL       |
|  4 | /tmp/BBB/bar | awaiting    |  200 | NULL       |
|  5 | /tmp/BBB/bar | awaiting    |  200 | NULL       |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

**UPDATE:**

The above result is correct for the first run. What I want to achieve in the second run (say request_id = 'aaa' ):

```
mysql> select * from test_limit;
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------------+
| id | folder       | status      | size | request_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------------+
|  1 | /tmp/AAA/bar | in_progress |  200 | bbb        |
|  2 | /tmp/AAA/bar | in_progress |  200 | bbb        |
|  3 | /tmp/AAA/bar | awaiting    |  200 | NULL       |
|  4 | /tmp/BBB/bar | in_progress |  200 | aaa        |
|  5 | /tmp/BBB/bar | in_progress |  200 | aaa        |
+----+--------------+-------------+------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

And in the third run it should not update anything because all the values are "in_progress".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I agree with Zach's direction but it is a little hard to figure out what you actually want.  You give us the result you don't want but not the result you do.

Comment: @Matt yes, you right =) , I've updated my answer to include what I want to achieve in the next sql execution.

Comment: Ahh I get it so 400 is the cap and you want to update based upon a running total......  I will have to think for a minute I don't really do too much in mysql a quick window function in sql-server, oracle etc would get you there fast......

Comment: But they're all bigger than 400!? !

Comment: @Strawberry,  apologies if I wasn't clear enough, I guess Matt summarized exactly what I was looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it took me a while to think through the logic.  Here is the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/227dd0/1

```
UPDATE test_limit u
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    t1.*
    ,f.NonAwaitingFolderTotal
    ,(@runtot := @runtot + t1.size) as RunningTotal
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        folder
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 'awaiting' THEN size ELSE 0 END) as NonAwaitingFolderTotal
      FROM
        test_limit t
      GROUP BY
        folder
      HAVING
        SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 'awaiting' THEN size ELSE 0 END) <= 400
      ORDER BY
        NonAwaitingFolderTotal, folder
      LIMIT 1
    ) f
    INNER JOIN test_limit t1
    ON f.folder = t1.folder
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @runtot:=0) var
  WHERE
    t1.status = 'awaiting'
)  t2
ON u.id = t2.id
AND (t2.NonAwaitingFolderTotal + t2.RunningTotal) <= 400
SET
  u.status = 'in_progress'
  ,u.request_id = @request_id
;
```

The logic goes like this

- find out folder to use and find the Non Awaiting Total Size that is currently in that folder.  Then select a folder by the lowest non awaiting size (in_progress,created) and if tied by folder name and then limit 1.
- Get a Running Total of All awaiting records in that folder to be used to determine which rows can be updated before hitting the max allowed.
- Do the update with a join to the results of the running total query where Total Size of the NonAwaiting records + the running total of that record are less than the 400 maximum.

And just because I want to keep this around somewhere the main issue was the running total you where using wasn't grouped by the right level.  here are a few running total & row number functions I worked through thinking about it.

```
SELECT 
  *
  ,(@foldercount := IF(@prevfolder=folder,@foldercount,@foldercount+1)) as FolderNum
  ,(@rownum := @rownum + 1) as RowNum
  ,(@grouprownum := IF(@prevfolder=folder,@grouprownum+1,1)) as GroupRowNum
  ,(@total := IF(@prevfolder=folder,@total + t.size,t.size)) as GroupRunningTotal
  ,(@GroupAwaitRunningTotal := IF(
        @prevfolder=folder
        ,IF(t.status = 'awaiting',@GroupAwaitRunningTotal + t.size,@GroupAwaitRunningTotal)
        ,IF(t.status = 'awaiting',t.size,0)
      )
   ) as GroupAwaitRunningTotal
   ,(@GroupNonAwaitRunningTotal := IF(
        @prevfolder=folder
        ,IF(t.status != 'awaiting',@GroupNonAwaitRunningTotal + t.size,@GroupNonAwaitRunningTotal)
        ,IF(t.status != 'awaiting',t.size,0)
      )
   ) as GroupNonAwaitRunningTotal
  ,(@runtot := @runtot + t.size) as RunningTotal
  ,@prevfolder:=folder
FROM 
  test_limit t
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT @prevfolder:=NULL, @GroupAwaitRunningTotal := 0
     ,@GroupNonAwaitRunningTotal := 0
     ,@total:=0, @rownum:=0, @grouprownum:=0, @runtot:=0, @foldercount:=0) var
```

Comment: @vor so I am curios if this works for you?  any tweaks needed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a stored procedure instead. Although it is longer than the solution using a query, you may find this procedural code easier to understand and maintain. Certainly the execution is convenient:

```
CALL process_test_limit('AAA');
```

How does it work? The procedure gets rows from `test_limit` ordered by `folder` and keeps track of the `id` until the running total hits 400 or the `folder` changes. If a folder already has a record with `status` 'in_process' then that folder will be ignored.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `process_test_limit`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `process_test_limit` (IN p_request_id VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_sqlsafeupdates  BOOLEAN;  -- State of SQL_SAFE_UPDATES at execution start
    DECLARE v_to_update       CHAR(64); -- Name of temp table to store IDs of rows to be updated
    DECLARE v_id              INT;
    DECLARE v_folder          VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE v_size            BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE v_running_total   BIGINT UNSIGNED  DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_prev_id         INT              DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE v_prev_folder     VARCHAR(255)     DEFAULT NULL;

    -- Cursor end handler flag (must be declared before cursors)
    DECLARE v_cursor_end   BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

    -- Main cursor to iterate through the rows of test_limit
    DECLARE c_test_limit CURSOR FOR
    SELECT tl.id
         , tl.folder
         , tl.size
      FROM test_limit tl
     WHERE tl.status = 'awaiting'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM test_limit tl_check
                        WHERE tl_check.folder = tl.folder
                          AND tl_check.status = 'in_progress'
                        LIMIT 1
                      )
     ORDER BY tl.folder -- Order is important: we process max one folder per call
            , tl.size
    ;

    -- Cursor end handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_cursor_end = TRUE;

    -- Remember the current state of SQL_SAFE_UPDATES, then disable it
    SET v_sqlsafeupdates = @@sql_safe_updates;
    SET @@sql_safe_updates = FALSE;

    -- Create temp table for tracking IDs of rows to update
    SET v_to_update = CONCAT(
        'process_test_limit_', CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS CHAR), '_tmp'
    );
    SET @create_tmp_table_sql = CONCAT(
        'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ', v_to_update, 
        ' (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=MEMORY'
    );
    PREPARE create_tmp_table_stmt FROM @create_tmp_table_sql;
    EXECUTE create_tmp_table_stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE create_tmp_table_stmt;

    -- Prepare statement for saving IDs into "to update" tmp table
    SET @save_id_sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', v_to_update, ' (id) VALUES (?)');
    PREPARE save_id_stmt FROM @save_id_sql;

    -- Open the cursor to enable us to read the ordered result set one record at a time
    OPEN c_test_limit;

    -- Process the ordered test_limit records one-by-one
    l_test_limit: LOOP

        -- Get the next record (advance the cursor)
        FETCH c_test_limit
         INTO v_id, v_folder, v_size
        ;

        -- Exit the loop if there are no more records to process
        IF v_cursor_end THEN
            LEAVE l_test_limit;
        END IF;

        -- First/same-as-last folder and running total not over 400? Save ID for update.
        IF (v_prev_folder IS NULL OR v_folder = v_prev_folder) AND v_running_total + v_size <= 400 THEN

            SET @id = CAST(v_id AS CHAR);
            EXECUTE save_id_stmt USING @id;

            -- Set variables for next iteration
            SET v_prev_id = v_id;
            SET v_prev_folder = v_folder;
            SET v_running_total = v_running_total + v_size;

        -- Different folder or running total over 400? Exit loop.
        ELSE

            LEAVE l_test_limit;

        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    -- Deallocate statement for inserting rows into temp table
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE save_id_stmt;

    -- Update rows
    SET @update_sql = CONCAT(
        'UPDATE test_limit t INNER JOIN ', v_to_update, ' tmp',
            ' ON t.id = tmp.id',
            ' SET t.status = ?,',
            ' t.request_id = ?'
    );
    SET @status = 'in_progress';
    SET @request_id = p_request_id;
    PREPARE update_stmt FROM @update_sql;
    EXECUTE update_stmt USING @status, @request_id;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_stmt;

    -- Drop temp table
    SET @drop_tmp_table_sql = CONCAT('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE ', v_to_update);
    PREPARE drop_tmp_table_stmt FROM @drop_tmp_table_sql;
    EXECUTE drop_tmp_table_stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE drop_tmp_table_stmt;

    -- Return SQL_SAFE_UPDATES to its original state at execution start
    SET @@sql_safe_updates = v_sqlsafeupdates;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The results do appear to satisfy your requirements:

```
-- Execution 1: 'AAA'
CALL process_test_limit('AAA');
SELECT * FROM test_limit;
-- id, folder, status, size, request_id
-- 1, /tmp/AAA/bar, in_progress, 200, AAA
-- 2, /tmp/AAA/bar, in_progress, 200, AAA
-- 3, /tmp/AAA/bar, awaiting, 200, 
-- 4, /tmp/BBB/bar, awaiting, 200, 
-- 5, /tmp/BBB/bar, awaiting, 200, 

-- Execution 2: 'BBB'
CALL process_test_limit('BBB');
SELECT * FROM test_limit;
-- id, folder, status, size, request_id
-- 1, /tmp/AAA/bar, in_progress, 200, AAA
-- 2, /tmp/AAA/bar, in_progress, 200, AAA
-- 3, /tmp/AAA/bar, in_progress, 200,
-- 4, /tmp/BBB/bar, awaiting, 200, BBB
-- 5, /tmp/BBB/bar, awaiting, 200, BBB

-- Execution 3: 'CCC'
CALL process_test_limit('CCC');
SELECT * FROM test_limit;
-- id, folder, status, size, request_id
-- 1, /tmp/AAA/bar, in_progress, 200, AAA
-- 2, /tmp/AAA/bar, in_progress, 200, AAA
-- 3, /tmp/AAA/bar, in_progress, 200,
-- 4, /tmp/BBB/bar, in_progress, 200, BBB
-- 5, /tmp/BBB/bar, in_progress, 200, BBB
```

Comment: very appreciate  your answer.  One thing that this query does that Is - it's updating all the records to "in_progress"

Comment: Oh, OK. So, the first thing I need to do is change >= 400 to =400. Let me refer to your updates too.

Comment: Having read your updates, I agree that my query does not solve your problem. I might be able to envision a solution in an `UPDATE` statement if, say, the size values are patterned and predictable. But I think it would be better to write a stored procedure. The algorithm would be easier to understand and performance would be better. Are you open to a stored procedure as a solution?

Comment: Yes, stored procedure is definitely and option. Would really appreciate if you can help me in this direction.

Comment: Hello Vor! Please see the stored procedure above and let me know if it is helpful to you.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive, It would probably take me some time to digest how it works. But I hope I can give you more up-votes.  Can I ask you a question, is there any way to get this stored procedure update `/tmp/BBB/bar`'s in the second execution. Sort of checking if there are no `in_progress` statuses  for other folders with the same path.  For example if some /tmp/AAA/bar already "in_progress" then don't set another '/tmp/AAAbar" to in_progress untill the first one changes it's status to "completed" or something like that ?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. To restate the requirement: the process should ignore a folder if a record exists for that folder in `in_progress` status. I would probably put criteria in the cursor query—probably a NOT EXISTS clause. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Hello @Vor! Please check out the updated solution and result sets. Hope it is helpful or at least interesting.